# Spring Data (JPA) - using generics in @Query

Tags: generics, spring-data-jpa

I wonder if it's possible to use generics in the named queries in spring data (using jpa myself), is it possible to do anything like this?

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface EnumerationRepository<T extends Enumeration> extends JpaRepository<T,Integer> {
  @Query("Select t.type from T t")
  public List<String> selectTypes();
}
```

Enumeration class being this

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Enumeration {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Column(name = "id", length = 3)
  private int id;
  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 30)
  private String type;

  // getters / setters .. etc 
}
```

I ommitted some fields in the Enumeration class for the sake of simplicity.

Tried this but obviously it complains cause class T is not mapped.

The point is because i have like 20+ tables that share some basic structure, and since i need queries to extract only data from columns, not the whole entity, would be nice to find a way to get the query in the "parent" repository and not having to replicate the code 20+ times.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If using [Spring Data JPA 1.4 or higher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e1919), the following will work:

```
@Query("Select t.type from #{#entityName} t")
```

Comment: Hi,  I using the same approach, is it possible to add where clause in the @Query statement. I am getting Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method on null context.

Comment: Yes, we can use `where` clause.

Comment: Note that you will also have to ensure your base repository is annotated with @NoRepositoryBean [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61182837/26510)