# Spring Data Repository without specifying Entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

With Spring Data you can make a Repository for a given entity:

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {...}
```

But what if you have a lot of custom queries not tied to a specific Entity?

None of the below work:

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepo {...}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository {...}
```

```java
@Component
public interface MyRepo extends Repository {...}
```

And so on..

Essentially what I want, is to be able to encapsulate some `@Query`s into an injectable class or interface.

Comment: Think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292963/spring-data-jpa-using-generics-in-query) will help you.

Comment: Not sure how that link relates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create spring repository without entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55513776/create-spring-repository-without-entity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generic entity superclass instead of a concrete entity. It's very usual to have an abstract superclass to declare the id of the entities or other common stuff.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }   
}
```

Then you can create a repository like this and autowire where you need it:

```
public interface MyRepo extends JpaRepository<AbstractEntity, Long> {

    @Query("...")
    myQueryMethod();
}
```

That said, Spring Data interfaces are designed to work with a root entity. I think that if you want to avoid it, you should use the underlying JPA layer (that is, use the EntityManager to execute queries instead of a Spring Data Repository).