# Spring JPA: BaseEntity is not mapped

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a `Spring Boot` project with `JPA Persistence`.
I have a Base Entity class like:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener::class)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
abstract class BaseEntity<T: Serializable> : Persistable<T> {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private var id: T? = null
    // ...
}
```

And Entity class like:

```
@Entity
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
class User(
    @Column
    val username: String,
    @Column
    val password: String,
    //...
) : BaseEntity<Long>()
```

I don't want to delete records physically from database so I added a `BaseRepository` class with overrided `deleteById()` method as below:

```
interface BaseRepository<T : BaseEntity<Long>?, ID> : JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    @Modifying
    @Query("update #{#entityName} o set o.deleted = true where o.id = ?1")
    override fun deleteById(@NonNull id: ID)
}
```

Now after running project I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'baseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Validation failed for query for method
public abstract void com.example.repo.BaseRepository.deleteById(java.lang.Object)!
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Annotate the `BaseRepository` with the `@NoRepositoryBean` annotation. This ensures that Spring Data JPA won’t try to create an implementation for the BaseRepository interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean 
interface BaseRepository<T : BaseEntity<Long>?, ID> : JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
     // ...
}
```